# rpd random path selection does not work in Juniper vMX

Tags: routing, juniper

I read a Junos documentation which said that:

```
In case of equal-cost paths for the same destination, the routing protocol daemon(rpd) randomly selects one of the available paths to balance load, while maintain packet ordering in case of equal paths
```

In addition, there was a following screenshot illustrating this statement:

[image: equal-cost paths]

When I try to replicate this behavior on MX series router, then looks like the random selection does not work:

```
root@vmx> show route 10.1/16    

inet.0: 26 destinations, 26 routes (26 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

10.1.1.0/24        *[Static/5] 00:00:01
                      to 172.20.66.2 via ge-0/0/4.0
                    > to 172.20.77.2 via ge-0/0/5.0
10.1.2.0/24        *[Static/5] 00:00:01
                      to 172.20.66.2 via ge-0/0/4.0
                    > to 172.20.77.2 via ge-0/0/5.0
10.1.3.0/24        *[Static/5] 00:00:01
                      to 172.20.66.2 via ge-0/0/4.0
                    > to 172.20.77.2 via ge-0/0/5.0
10.1.4.0/24        *[Static/5] 00:00:01
                      to 172.20.66.2 via ge-0/0/4.0
                    > to 172.20.77.2 via ge-0/0/5.0

root@vmx>
```

What might cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that what you're seeing is a cosmetic issue.  The `>` placement doesn't matter.

**Routing Table**

As you can see, 3 of the routes in my lab are appearing similarly to the example you provided.  However, the actual *forwarding* is determined by looking at the forwarding table.

```
root@vmx1# run show route protocol static

inet.0: 13 destinations, 13 routes (13 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

10.10.0.0/24       *[Static/5] 00:00:45
                    > to 1.1.1.2 via ge-0/0/0.0
                      to 3.3.3.0 via ge-0/0/2.0
10.20.0.0/24       *[Static/5] 00:00:09
                      to 1.1.1.2 via ge-0/0/0.0
                    > to 3.3.3.0 via ge-0/0/2.0
10.30.0.0/24       *[Static/5] 00:00:09
                    > to 1.1.1.2 via ge-0/0/0.0
                      to 3.3.3.0 via ge-0/0/2.0
10.40.0.0/24       *[Static/5] 00:00:09
                    > to 1.1.1.2 via ge-0/0/0.0
                      to 3.3.3.0 via ge-0/0/2.0
```

**Forwarding Table**

I just have one route as an example, but they would all appear the same way.  As Jeff Wheeler mentioned, you do need the `load-balance per-packet` policy configured, please note that `per-packet` is a misnomer in Juniper, it does actually mean per-flow.

The `ulst` entry, stands for unicast list (of `ucst` next-hops), as you can see both interfaces are present.  Random selection happens between anything present in a `ulst`.  This is the authoritative place to verify forwarding behavior.

```
root@vmx1# run show route forwarding-table destination 10.10.0.0/24
Routing table: default.inet
Internet:
Enabled protocols: Bridging,
Destination        Type RtRef Next hop           Type Index    NhRef Netif
10.10.0.0/24       user     0                    ulst   262142     5
                              1.1.1.2            ucst      556     3 ge-0/0/0.0
                              3.3.3.0            ucst      559     3 ge-0/0/2.0
```

**Forwarding Table (without `load-balance per-packet`)**

Conversely, if we remove the policy, you would see the same output from `show route`, but the forwarding behavior would only select one next-hop.  The key difference here is that `ulst` is **not** present, meaning that no load balancing will occur.

```
root@vmx1# run show route forwarding-table destination 10.10.0.0/24
Routing table: default.inet
Internet:
Enabled protocols: Bridging,
Destination        Type RtRef Next hop           Type Index    NhRef Netif
10.10.0.0/24       user     0 1.1.1.2            ucst      556     5 ge-0/0/0.0
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this out in practice by creating several traffic flows to addresses in the networks seen in the output of `show route protocol static` command. Traffic is indeed load-balanced per-flow. Looks like some sort of hashing algorithm is used to load-balance the traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you were reading a document for a platform that doesn't support `load-balance per-packet`?  Perhaps you can link where you were reading.

The vMX will allow you to install both routes at once.  Configure as below, and see the [documentation](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/concept/policy-per-packet-load-balancing-overview.html) for details.

```
routing-options {
    forwarding-table {
        export FWDTBL;
    }
}
policy-options {
    policy-statement FWDTBL {
        term all {
            then {
                accept;
                load-balance per-packet;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It was a JNCIA-Junos study material at Junos Genius environment. I tried with the `per-packet` load-balance mode, but unfortunately it didn't help. I also configured `enhanced-ip` mode under `chassis` configuration and rebooted the vMX, but the random selection does not work. There are no "unsupported platform" or similar comments in the configuration.

Comment: Maybe they've used a generous definition of "random" on the vMX implementation.